# R console issue under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, r

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. The R console seems not to be working correctly after my upgrade. The problem is that when I paste several lines of code into the R console, only a few lines of code get appended (seems to be a limit on the number of lines to be pasted). For example, try to paste the following into the R console, and only a few entries (up to 158 lines get appended correctly). I tested this with other R versions (4.1.2; 4-2.0; 4-2.1) and the issue is present in all of them. The issue did not exist under Ubuntu 20. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   rm(list=ls())

   codes.vector = character(1)

   codes.vector[1] = "ADS.DE"
   codes.vector[2] = "AIR.PA"
   codes.vector[3] = "ALV.DE"
   codes.vector[4] = "BAS.DE"
   codes.vector[5] = "BAYN.DE"
   codes.vector[6] = "BMW.DE"
   codes.vector[7] = "BEI.DE"
   codes.vector[8] = "BNR.DE"
   codes.vector[9] = "CON.DE"
   codes.vector[10]= "1COV.DE"
   codes.vector[11]= "DTG.DE"
   codes.vector[12]= "DBK.DE"
   codes.vector[13]= "DPW.DE"
   codes.vector[14]= "DTE.DE"
   codes.vector[15]= "EOAN.DE"
   codes.vector[16]= "FMEA.SG"
   codes.vector[17]= "FRE.DE"
   codes.vector[18]= "HEI.DE"
   codes.vector[19]= "HFG.DE"
   codes.vector[20]= "HEN3.DE"
   codes.vector[21]= "IFX.DE"
   codes.vector[22]= "LIN.DE"
   codes.vector[23]= "MBG.DE"
   codes.vector[24]= "MRK.DE"
  codes.vector[25]= "MTX.DE"
  codes.vector[26]= "PAH3.DE"
   codes.vector[27]= "PUM.DE"
   codes.vector[28]= "QIA.DE"
   codes.vector[29]= "RWE.DE"
   codes.vector[30]= "SAP.DE"
   codes.vector[31]= "SRT3.DE"
   codes.vector[32]= "SIE.DE"
   codes.vector[33]= "SHL.DE"
   codes.vector[34]= "SY1.DE"
   codes.vector[35]= "VOW.VI"
   codes.vector[36]= "VNA.DE"
   codes.vector[37]= "ZAL.DE"
   codes.vector[38] = "MMM"
   codes.vector[39] = "ATVI"
   codes.vector[40] = "ADBE"
   codes.vector[41] = "AMD"
   codes.vector[42] = "ABNB"
   codes.vector[43] = "ALGN"
   codes.vector[44] = "GOOGL"
   codes.vector[45] = "GOOG"
   codes.vector[46] = "AMZN"
   codes.vector[47] = "AEP"
   codes.vector[48] = "AXP"
   codes.vector[49] = "AMGN"
   codes.vector[50] = "ADI"
   codes.vector[51] = "ANSS"
   codes.vector[52] = "AAPL"
   codes.vector[53] = "AMAT"
   codes.vector[54] = "ASML"
   codes.vector[55] = "AZN"
   codes.vector[56] = "TEAM"
   codes.vector[57] = "ADSK"
   codes.vector[58] = "ADP"
   codes.vector[59] = "B1C.SG"
   codes.vector[60] = "BIIB"
   codes.vector[61] = "BA"
   codes.vector[62] = "BKNG"
   codes.vector[63] = "AVGO"
   codes.vector[64] = "CDNS"
   codes.vector[65] = "CAT"
   codes.vector[66] = "CHTR"
   codes.vector[67] = "CVX"
   codes.vector[68] = "CTAS"
   codes.vector[69] = "CSCO"
   codes.vector[70] = "KO"
   codes.vector[71] = "CTSH"
   codes.vector[72] = "CMCSA"
   codes.vector[73] = "CEG"
   codes.vector[74] = "CPRT"
   codes.vector[75] = "COST"
   codes.vector[76] = "CRWD"
   codes.vector[77] = "CSX"
   codes.vector[78] = "DDOG"
   codes.vector[79] = "DXCM"
   codes.vector[80] = "DOCU"
   codes.vector[81] = "DLTR"
   codes.vector[82] = "DOW"
   codes.vector[83] = "EBAY"
   codes.vector[84] = "EA"
   codes.vector[85] = "FAST"
   codes.vector[86] = "FISV"
   codes.vector[87] = "FTNT"
   codes.vector[88] = "FOX"
   codes.vector[89] = "GILD"
   codes.vector[90] = "GS"
   codes.vector[91] = "HD"
   codes.vector[92] = "HON"
   codes.vector[93] = "IDXX"
   codes.vector[94] = "ILMN"
   codes.vector[95] = "INTC"
   codes.vector[96] = "IBM.VI"
   codes.vector[97] = "INTU"
   codes.vector[98] = "ISRG"
   codes.vector[99] = "JD"
   codes.vector[100] = "JNJ"
   codes.vector[101] = "JPM"
   codes.vector[102] = "KDP"
   codes.vector[103] = "KLAC"
   codes.vector[104] = "KHC"
   codes.vector[105] = "LRCX"
   codes.vector[106] = "LCID"
   codes.vector[107] = "LULU"
   codes.vector[108] = "MAR"
   codes.vector[109] = "MRVL"
   codes.vector[110] = "MTCH"
   codes.vector[111] = "MCD"
   codes.vector[112] = "MELI"
   codes.vector[113] = "MRK"
   codes.vector[114] = "META"
   codes.vector[115] = "MCHP"
   codes.vector[116] = "MU"
   codes.vector[117] = "MSFT"
    codes.vector[118] = "MRNA"
   codes.vector[119] = "MDLZ"
   codes.vector[120] = "MNST"
   codes.vector[121] = "NTES"
   codes.vector[122] = "NFLX"
   codes.vector[123] = "NKE"
   codes.vector[124] = "NVDA"
   codes.vector[125] = "NXPI"
   codes.vector[126] = "ORLY"
   codes.vector[127] = "OKTA"
   codes.vector[128] = "ODFL"
   codes.vector[129] = "PCAR"
   codes.vector[130] = "PANW"
   codes.vector[131] = "PAYX"
   codes.vector[132] = "PYPL"
   codes.vector[133] = "PEP"
   codes.vector[134] = "PDD"
   codes.vector[135] = "PG"
   codes.vector[136] = "QCOM"
   codes.vector[137] = "REGN"
   codes.vector[138] = "ROST"
   codes.vector[139] = "CRM"
   codes.vector[140] = "SGEN"
   codes.vector[141] = "SIRI"
   codes.vector[142] = "SWKS"
   codes.vector[143] = "SPLK"
   codes.vector[144] = "SBUX"
   codes.vector[145] = "SNPS"
   codes.vector[146] = "TMUS"
   codes.vector[147] = "TSLA"
   codes.vector[148] = "TXN"
   codes.vector[149] = "TRV"
   codes.vector[150] = "UNH"
   codes.vector[151] = "VRSN"
   codes.vector[152] = "VRSK"
   codes.vector[153] = "VZ"
   codes.vector[154] = "VRTX"
   codes.vector[155] = "VTRS"
   codes.vector[156] = "V"
   codes.vector[157] = "WBA"
   codes.vector[158] = "WMT"
   codes.vector[159] = "DIS"
   codes.vector[160] = "WDAY"
   codes.vector[161] = "XEL"
   codes.vector[162] = "ZM"
   codes.vector[163] = "ZS
```

Comment: seems a `gnome-terminal` issue/setting, as I don't see the problem in `mate-terminal`.

Comment: Please do not put `rm(list=ls())` in sample code. It deletes the environment of whomever runs it.

Comment: Ubuntu 20 refers to Ubuntu Core 20 as that is the only version of Ubuntu using one digit. Please edit and correct if you did not upgrade from core.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a limitation in the terminal emulator you use. Still, it is wise not to copy paste large chunks of code. Instead use `source()`, and leave copy/paste for smaller, manageable pieces of text you can oversee.

Alternatively, you can [turn "bracketed paste" off](https://askubuntu.com/a/738649/558158) to revert to the traditional behavior of the terminal, where pasted lines are executed one-by-one.